# Cannot listen to server running on ec2 amazon linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, nestjs

I have a nestjs server running on ec2. My steps were as follows:

1. install git and node
2. git clone nest-project
3. cd nest-project (/home/ec2-user/nest-project)
4. npm i
5. npm run build
6. npm run start:prod

It shows everything is working fine.

My security inbound rules are as follows

[security inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwQ9D.png)
[Error when I access through public ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFObX.png)

I am trying to access this using :3000, which is the port defined in the `src/main.ts` file and stated in [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#running-the-application)

Comment: If you get a Connection Refused error, that means you successfully reached the server but the server is not listening on the port you specified.  Are you sure your application is listening on all addresses?  Are you sure the port is properly specified in your url, `i.p.ad.dr:3000/...` *not* `i.p.ad.dr/3000` ?

Comment: Yes port is specified correctly

Answer (score 0):

By default Nest project only replies to requests made on `localhost`, not on the public interface.

If you want to server to be publicly available you should modify the `app.listen()` method to specify the IP address and port you want your Nest application to listen on. For example: `await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0')`